# How to plot 2D vector field in single picture using Hue and Brightness method with Digital Micrograph script?

Tags: dm-script

I would like to to plot 2D vector field in a single picture using the Hue & brightness method, i.e., Hue to direction (or say, phase), brightness to magnitude.
Such method is often used to visualize e.g., magnetic domains, vortex etc which are reconstructed from Lorenz microscopy.

As input, I have two images of size 1024*1024, pixels contain the magnitude of X and Y component of the vector field.

Since DM does not support native HSL color scheme, I think one should first uses a group of self defined functions to convert HSL to RGB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use RGB images in DigitalMicrograph, so you will have to do the conversion from HSB to RGB in your script code, and then create the according RGB image.
Luckily, there is a demonstration script on the Gatan script resources webpage which does exactly that! You can basically use the script as it is shown there.

[Gatan Script Resources](http://www.gatan.com/resources/scripts)

Link to script-file:
[Display as HSB](http://www.gatan.com/sites/default/files/Scripts/Display%20as%20HSB.s)

Note, the script uses *complex images* as input - just as a convenient container to combine two images into a single one. The test function demonstrates this though.